# PHP + jQuery: grabbing data from a PHP form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I've done a lot of searching about this and I've tried pretty much everything that has been suggested to no effect.

I have 2 series of radio buttons (only publishing one series):

```
    <div class='place PP'>
              <input type='radio' name='hotel' class='hotel' value='Natura Cabana Boutique Hotel' required>
              Natura Cabana Boutique Hotel (24.300 DKK)
              <input type='hidden' name='hotelPrice' class='Natura Cabana Boutique Hotel' value='24.300'>
            </div>
    <div class='place PP'>
              <input type='radio' name='hotel' class='hotel' value='Casa Maravilla' required>
              Casa Maravilla (42.500 DKK)
              <input type='hidden' name='hotelPrice' class='Casa Maravilla' value='42.500'>
            </div>
    <div class='place PP'>
              <input type='radio' name='hotel' class='hotel' value='Casa Veintiuno' required>
              Casa Veintiuno (31.500 DKK)
              <input type='hidden' name='hotelPrice' class='Casa Veintiuno' value='31.500'>
            </div>
```

The value and the price are retrieved from a database.

My jQuery code to show the price looks like this:

```
$(".hotel").change(function() {
    var hotel = $(this).val();

    switch (hotel) {
        case "Natura Cabana Boutique Hotel":
            var x = new Number(24.300);
            $("#price").val(x.toFixed(3) + " DKK");
            break;
        case "Casa Maravilla":
            var x = new Number(42.500);
            $("#price").val(x.toFixed(3) + " DKK");
            break;
        case "Casa Veintiuno":
            var x = new Number(31.500);
            $("#price").val(x.toFixed(3) + " DKK");
            break;
        // more jQuery code
        } });
```

How can I pass 2 values and replace the fixed numbers I used with the value of $hotelPrice?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see any calls to the database? Are you asking how to make a database calls to retrieve the values based on the hotel?

Comment: Hi Chitowns24, no. I omitted all that code. What I'm asking is how to grab 2 values from an input radio (or an input radio or input hidden) with my jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Given you've got the price embedded 3 ways (plaintext, hidden form field, JS switch statement), it's rather duplicative. You could ditch everything except the hidden form field, for instance:

```
<input type='radio' name='hotel' class='hotel' value='Casa Maravilla' required>
Casa Maravilla (<span class="displayPrice">42.500</span> DKK)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---note new span
<input type='hidden' name='hotelPrice' class='Casa Maravilla' value='42.500'>
```

Then:

```
$(".hotel").change(function() {
    price = $(this).siblings('.hotelPrice');
    $(this).parent().children('.displayPrice').val(price);
});
```

Since every DOM node "knows" where it is in the tree, you can use `.siblings()` to retrieve the hotel's price from the hidden form field, then `.parent().children('...')` to find the new span and insert the retrieved price.

Comment: Hi Marc B, thanks. When I did this, instead of getting a number, I got a NaN. Thanks for trying anyway.